# Issues with Domain Mapping on Cloud Run - Custom domains (GCLB)

Tags: google-cloud-run, domain-mapping

I have an app running on cloud run and I'm trying to map one of my domains to that app. I'm using the Custom Domain option but the SSL certificate provisioning can't seem to be provisioned.

[SSL Certificate details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6y4KY.png)

Has anyone solved this issue?

Documentation: https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/troubleshooting

Comment: `can't seem to make it work` is not a good problem description. Provide details on what does not work.